# OpenShift Exceeding disk quota

Tags: openshift

i'm running my application in openshift enviroment

And i got this error bellow

> cp: writing `/tmp/haproxy.cfg.160985': Disk quota exceeded Warning:
>   Gear 5355f14ae0b8cd3611000192 is using 100.0% of disk quota Failed to
>   execute: 'control update-cluster' for
>   /var/lib/openshift/5355f14ae0b8cd3611000192/haproxy

I try to increase the disk quota but the error keeps

> cp: writing `/tmp/haproxy.cfg.160985': Disk quota exceeded Warning:
>   Gear 5355f14ae0b8cd3611000192 is using 100.0% of disk quota Failed to
>   execute: 'control update-cluster' for
>   /var/lib/openshift/5355f14ae0b8cd3611000192/haproxy

Answer (score 1):

Run the `rhc app-tidy <appname>` command to clean things up a bit and then run the `rhc cartridge storage <cartridge> -a <appname> --add <amount>` to increase your disk quota. That should take care of everything for you.